# Create Custom Ubuntu ISO Installation Medium

Tags: 20.04, grub2, system-installation, gui, iso

Modifications of the Ubuntu ISO would be great in offline installations for my purpose. There is Cubic, but for what I've been doing it has only attempted to create Live CD type setups. What I am interested in is to add a GUI, and a few packages such as xterm and Firefox, and to have the resulting ISO equipped with whatever packages installed. I've heard of pre-seeding, but I have not come across it being used offline.

The primary reason for this was an offline installation for systems I have not yet wired up to a network.

What I have done so far is to use Cubic and an alteration of this: [Ubuntu auto Install Generator](https://github.com/covertsh/ubuntu-autoinstall-generator#ubuntu-autoinstall-generator). After using this tool, I went ahead and modified the ISO with Cubic.

What I have not tried yet is to use **only** the Auto-install Generator. I do not yet know whether it will work very well with 20.04.3 Ubuntu. There has been some feedback that the *live server* version is troublesome to install as unattended though.

Last bit would be: I am not savvy on what files to edit when attempting to install a GUI using Cubic. Obviously the display manager would need to be configured; for this purpose  Sddm was being used.

What can I do to make a non-live CD-type, offline, installation for 20.04.3 Ubuntu Server with a GUI?

Comment: You do realize Ubuntu 20.04.3 is very old being a mid-2021 respin of 20.04 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/) and uses *revoked* keys; thus won't be able to be installed on modern/updated Secure-uEFI systems. Why not built from a *patched* system?  (eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/ and note the second paragraph or "*Unlike previous point releases, 20.04.6 is a refresh of the amd64 installer media after recent key revocations, re-enabling their usage on Secure Boot enabled systems.*"

Comment: Excellent point. Also, I found [this](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/a-tool-to-modify-live-server-isos/22195).

Comment: If the target computers are reasonably similar, you can make a master installation, an [Ubuntu OEM system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview), and clone it (make an image with Clonezilla, and then extract it to the other computers). See also [this link](https://devicetests.com/pre-install-ubuntu-oem-installation-guide).